# How to save strings into a Visual Basic Array?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vbc

I am wondering how I would go about saving a string into an array.Its a beginner question , but i really need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Saving to a string array? A char array? "saving"... to disk? to memory? This question needs more specifics.

Comment: The question is a bit unspecific, since there are a lot of different array-types.

Answer (score 0):

A string array is created in various ways. In the VB.NET language you can **create the array** with all its data in an **initialization statement**. For Example:

```
Dim arrayName() As String = {"string1", "string2", "string3"}
```

You can **pre-allocate** the array and then **assign values** to its *memory locations* separately. For example:

```
Dim newArray(0 to 2) As String
newArray(0) = "string1"
newArray(1) = "string2"
newArray(2) = "string3"
```